# Eclipse 3.6 lag when copy and pasting

Tags: php, javascript, eclipse, dojo-dnd

I'm having a strange problem with Eclipse 3.6 where copy and pasting causes a lot of lag (total eclipse lockup for 5-10 seconds).  I'm using the Helios 3.6 PHP build but have also tried Galileo to no avail.  On .php files editing PHP code, it is fine and there is no delay.  Same with .html and .js, but it only happens when I try and copy and paste Dojo Script (which is basically Javascript) embedded in a .php file.  What may be causing the issue is it's not declared as:

```
<script type="text/javascript" event="onClick" args="evt">
```

but rather as:

```
<script type="dojo/method" event="onClick" args="evt">
```

So in the Editor, there is no special formatting at all because I guess the IDE doesn't recognize the 'language' that it is supposed to be.  As a result, the text is pure black with no formatting, font changes or highlighting of any kind.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Disabling `Hyperlinking` fixed this for me.  You could probably also just change the `Default modifier key` to something other than `Ctrl`.

Go to **Window** -> **Preferences** -> **General** -> **Editors** -> **Text Editors** -> **Hyperlinking** and uncheck `Enable on demand hyperlink style navigation` to disable.

Credit to nitind for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Such lags are usually due to some validation process that timeout (or generate tons of errors like in [this thread](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&goto=529946&))

Could you check what happens when you deactivate some or all of the Javascript validations?

Comment: Hey VonC, sorry for the lng response.  This didnt work.  I disabled all JS validation and the delay was still there.  Any other ideas?

Comment: @Paul: not at the moment except to check if there is some inclusion mechanism that could avoid you the copy task (and its associated delay). Other than that, it's back to a bug report site to mention this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to the Ctrl key activating hyperlink detection: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=328966

Comment: Disabling hyperlinking fixed this for me.  Ctrl is by default set to activate hyperlinking.  A bad choice if you ask me.